# Send email in a tabular format using SQL Server database mail

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

[image]

I have created SSIS package which has 1 SQL task (stored procedure which returns list of below 4 columns. How will achieve the following table to be sent through email. Immediate Next task here what I would do is create another stored procdure which accepts the result set from 1st stored proc through another Sql task and 2nd stored proc contains msdb_SendDBemail call . Is there any better approach

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this to get data in tabular format. To execute row by row you need to implement a cursor like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SendNewDeviceInfoToEmployee]  

AS  
BEGIN  
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Mbody VARCHAR(MAX), 
@Sub VARCHAR(500), 
@EmpEmailPwdId BIGINT, 
@Emp_nm VARCHAR(150), 
@ToEmailid VARCHAR(150), 
@NewEmailId VARCHAR(150), 
DECLARE @Recipients VARCHAR(max)

DECLARE SendautoLoginDtl CURSOR FOR
SELECT EmpEmailPwdId, EmpName, ToEmailid, NewEmailId, EmpPassword 
FROM EmployeeEmailIdPassword WHERE ISNULL(Freeze,'N') = 'N' AND ISNULL(IsMailSent,'N') = 'N' AND ISNULL(ToEmailId,'') <> '' AND ISNULL(NewEmailId,'') <> ''
ORDER BY EmpEmailPwdId

OPEN SendautoLoginDtl;
FETCH NEXT FROM SendautoLoginDtl INTO @EmpEmailPwdId, @emp_nm, @ToEmailid, @NewEmailId
WHILE( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )
BEGIN

SET @xml = CAST(( SELECT [Rank] AS 'td','',[Player Name] AS 'td','', [Ranking Points] AS 'td','', Country AS 'td'
FROM #Temp 
ORDER BY Rank 
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

SET @Mbody =N'<html><body><H3>Tennis Rankings Info</H3>
        <table border = 1> 
        <tr>
        <th> Rank </th> <th> Player Name </th> <th> Ranking Points </th> <th> Country </th></tr>'    

        SET @body = @body + @xml +'</table></body></html>' 

SET @sub='Your New Device Details - ' + @emp_nm  

set @Recipients =  @ToEmailid 

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail '<YourDBMailProfileName>' , 
@recipients = @Recipients ,
@copy_recipients = @NewEmailId,
@subject = @sub ,
@body = @Mbody ,  
@body_format = 'HTML'  

--Update table if required
UPDATE <YourTable>
SET IsMailSent = 'Y'
WHERE EmpEmailPwdId = @EmpEmailPwdId

FETCH NEXT FROM SendautoLoginDtl INTO @EmpEmailPwdId, @emp_nm, @ToEmailid, @NewEmailId, @EmpPassword
END

CLOSE SendautoLoginDtl;
DEALLOCATE SendautoLoginDtl;

END
```

You can learn about cursor [**here**](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/).

Comment: Above solution will not loop through the table rows. I want the looping through the table rows

Comment: @NAGARAJAHI You need to implement either while loop or cursor for this.

Comment: @NAGARAJAHI Updated my answer for row by row execution.

Answer (score 2):

Nice thread on stack exchange: [Need to Send a formatted HTML Email via Database Mail in Sql Server 2008 R2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83776/need-to-send-a-formatted-html-email-via-database-mail-in-sql-server-2008-r2)

It has an answer with a code of stored procedure `dbo.HtmlTable` that can generate HTML for further use in database mail:

```
CREATE table ##foo (bar1 int, bar2 varchar(20), bar3 datetime)
INSERT into ##foo values (1, 'Abcdef', getdate())
INSERT into ##foo values (2, 'Ghijkl', '05/05/15')

DECLARE @tableHtml varchar(max)
EXEC dbo.HtmlTable
    '##foo',
    @tableHtml output
PRINT @tableHtml
```

@tableHtml will contain html that renders into:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jc014.jpg]